# Conflict between fragment lifecycle flow in (4.0,4.1) and 4.2+ when oncreateoptionmenu used

Tags: android, android-fragments, lifecycle

On checking my code on different devices the log details were-
**below android 4.2 version** devices *Oncreateoptionmenu* calling **2 times**

and the flow to calling Override methods(Life cycle) in different manner.

### issue

please check second log of (4.0.2, and 4.1)

### Code

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.e("aaaaaaaaa", "....onCreate");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Log.e("aaaaaaaaa", "....onCreateView");

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,
                false);

        init();



        return rootView;
    }



 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    Log.e("aaaaaaaaa", "....onCreateOptionsMenu");
    // menuIsInflated = false;

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_employeelist, menu);
    SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new searchfilter());
}


private class searchfilter implements OnQueryTextListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newtext) {


            Log.i("", "onquery......text.....listner..");


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Log.e("search query...", query);
            return false;
        }

    }

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    Log.e("aaaaaaa", ".....onPrepareOptionsMenu");
}
```

### output for Two different emulator

.
.

### (1)4.0.3 and 4.1

firsttime open fragment

```
01-28 15:30:15.090: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreate
01-28 15:30:15.090: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreateView
01-28 15:30:15.120: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreateOptionsMenu
01-28 15:30:15.170: E/aaaaaaa(21867): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
```

second time open fragment

```
01-28 15:30:19.320: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreate
01-28 15:30:19.320: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreateOptionsMenu
01-28 15:30:19.350: I/(21867): onquery......text.....listner..
01-28 15:30:19.350: E/aaaaaaa(21867): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
01-28 15:30:19.350: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreateView
01-28 15:30:19.370: E/aaaaaaaaa(21867): ....onCreateOptionsMenu
01-28 15:30:19.380: I/(21867): onquery......text.....listner..
01-28 15:30:19.390: E/aaaaaaa(21867): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
```

### (2) >4.2(4.2 or greter divices or emulator)

firsttime open fragment

```
01-28 16:23:46.208: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreate
01-28 16:23:46.208: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreateView
01-28 16:23:46.329: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreateOptionsMenu
01-28 16:23:46.395: E/aaaaaaa(11232): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
01-28 16:23:46.397: E/aaaaaaa(11232): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
```

secondtime open fragment

```
01-28 16:24:02.923: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreate
01-28 16:24:02.923: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreateView
01-28 16:24:02.943: E/aaaaaaaaa(11232): ....onCreateOptionsMenu
01-28 16:24:02.948: I/(11232): onquery......text.....listner..
01-28 16:24:02.948: E/aaaaaaa(11232): .....onPrepareOptionsMenu
```

### xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_employee_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also put the xml for the layout ?

Comment: sry ....pls now check ... there is only listview nothing other